# Updating the database from 1.5.1.3 to 1.5.3.1 OpenCart

Tags: mysql, upgrade, opencart

I'm trying to pass data from my table OpenCart version 1.5.1.3 to version 1.5.3.1. I'll be using a new theme and only a few of the modules used in the previous version, but do not want to lose the data records of customers, sales and products.

Bearing this in mind I guess the easiest way would be estrair the table to a SQL script (I used phpmyadmin), but there are some differences between the versions for the database schema and data so I am not able to pass data from a table another.

As an example I'll use the table "address" 1.5.1.3 version that has the following structure when exported by phpmyadmin:

```
INSERT INTO `address` (`address_id`, `customer_id`, `firstname`, `lastname`, `company`, `address_1`, `address_2`, `city`, `postcode`, `country_id`, `zone_id`) VALUES
(6, 6, 'Fulano', 'Silva', '', 'My Street, 455', 'Neighborhood 1', 'City 1', 'd9c 5t7', 30, 464),
(2, 2, 'Cicrano', 'Souza', '', 'My Avenue, 921', 'Neighborhood 2', 'City 2', 'd9c 5t7', 30, 464),
(4, 4, 'Beltrano', 'Cabrito', '', 'My Street 2, 191', 'Neighborhood 3', 'City 3', 'd9c 3t7', 30, 464);
```

And the database version 1.5.3.1 follows this model:

```
INSERT INTO `address` (`address_id`, `customer_id`, `firstname`, `lastname`, `apelido`, `company`, `company_id`, `tax_id`, `address_1`, `numero`, `address_2`, `complemento`, `city`, `postcode`, `country_id`, `zone_id`) VALUES
(6, 6, 'Fulano', 'Silva', '', '', '', '', 'My Street', '455', 'Neighborhood 1', '', 'City 1', 'd9c 5t7', 30, 464),
(2, 2, 'Beltrano', 'Cabrito', '', '', '', '', '', 'My Street 2', '191', 'Neighborhood 3', '', 'City 3', 'd9c 3t7', 30, 464);
```

This is repeated in several tables, now how do I get only the data you want from v1.5.1.3 to v1.5.3.1 using SQL or other simpler if any?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is why the upgrade script is there. You can find out how to upgrade [here](http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=documentation/documentation&path=98)

Comment: I understand, had already taken a look at it, but I have many modules installed, some of which changed the database. What I do is create a new installation of OpenCart using the latest version and populate the database with the data of my virtual store.

Comment: Modules that have changed the database are fine. The upgrade merely adds/removes columns as needed to comply with the current version. Make a backup of your database first, then try and upgrade it